# FIFO, RR and Priority with threads on Mac vs. Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, macos

I am creating a program that performs tasks reading through excel files and giving me outputs accordingly. This exact code works on Mac when compiled with `gcc -c main.c` but when run on Linux it doesn't create the threads or perform any tasks:

```
  else if(strcmp(argv[1],"multi")==0) {
    if(argv[2]==NULL) {
      printf("Multi-thread mode with no parameters\n");
      pthread_create(&tid[0], &attr, task1, &(thread_ids[0]));
      pthread_create(&tid[1], &attr, task2, &(thread_ids[1]));
      pthread_create(&tid[2], &attr, task3, &(thread_ids[2]));
    } else if(strcmp(argv[2],"sched")==0) {
      if(argv[3]==NULL) {
           fprintf(stderr, "No scheduling parameter given, options are FIFO or RR\n");
      } else if(strcmp(argv[3],"FIFO")==0){ /* First In First Out */
           printf("Scheduling FIFO\n");
           pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_FIFO);
      } else if(strcmp(argv[3], "RR")==0){ /* Round Robin */
         printf("Do RR algorithm\n");
         pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_RR);
         schedparam.sched_priority = 10;
             pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
             pthread_create(&tid[0], &attr, task1, NULL);
             pthread_create(&tid[1], &attr, task2, NULL);
         pthread_create(&tid[2], &attr, task3, NULL);
         pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
         pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
         pthread_join(tid[2], NULL);
      }
      else{
           fprintf(stderr, "Scheduling parameter invalid, only RR and FIFO accepted\n");
      }
    } else if(strcmp(argv[2], "priority")==0){
      if(argv[3]==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "No task parameter given for priority\n");
      } else{

          if(atoi(argv[3])==1){
              if(strcmp(argv[4], "high")==0){
                  schedparam.sched_priority = 2;
                  pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
                  pthread_create(&tid[0], &attr, task1, &(thread_ids[0]));
              }
              else if(strcmp(argv[4], "low")==0){
                  schedparam.sched_priority = 75;
                  pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
                  pthread_create(&tid[0], &attr, task1, &(thread_ids[0]));
              }
              schedparam.sched_priority = 20;
              pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
              pthread_create(&tid[1], &attr, task2, &(thread_ids[1]));
              pthread_create(&tid[2], &attr, task3, &(thread_ids[2]));
          }
          else if(atoi(argv[3])==2){
              if(strcmp(argv[4], "high")==0){
                  schedparam.sched_priority = 2;
                  pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
                  pthread_create(&tid[1], &attr, task2, &(thread_ids[1]));
              }
              else if(strcmp(argv[4], "low")==0){
                  schedparam.sched_priority = 75;
                  pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
                  pthread_create(&tid[1], &attr, task2, &(thread_ids[1]));
              }
              schedparam.sched_priority = 20;
              pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
              pthread_create(&tid[0], &attr, task1, &(thread_ids[0]));
              pthread_create(&tid[2], &attr, task3, &(thread_ids[2]));
          }
          else if(atoi(argv[3])==3){
              if(strcmp(argv[4], "high")==0){
                  schedparam.sched_priority = 2;
                  pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
                  pthread_create(&tid[2], &attr, task3, &(thread_ids[2]));
              }
              else if(strcmp(argv[4], "low")==0){
                  schedparam.sched_priority = 75;
                  pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
                  pthread_create(&tid[2], &attr, task3, &(thread_ids[2]));
              }
              schedparam.sched_priority = 20;
              pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedparam);
              pthread_create(&tid[0], &attr, task1, &(thread_ids[0]));
              pthread_create(&tid[1], &attr, task2, &(thread_ids[1]));
          }
      }

  }
```

Can someone assist me as to why this isn't transferring over between Mac and Linux? If a user types in `./project multi sched FIFO/RR` it should schedule according to their choice. Like said above, this works on a Mac and not on Linux, very confused why not. I also noticed my Priority isn't altering/working either. I'm very stumped by this issue. I appreciate all assistance.

Comment: Have you checked the return values of the various `pthread_*` functions? That will give you a clue.

Comment: this is a run time question.  For such questions, you need to post code that cleanly compiles, contains no superflus functionality, still exhibits the problem.  Along with the code, you need to post some example input, the expected output and the actual output.  Otherwise, how are you expecting us to debug the problem?

Comment: the snippet of posted code has some logic problems.. It is expecting that the user entered valid parameters. (Never trust the user to do the right thing)   for instance when `argv[3]` is 3, then if `argv[4]` is neither 'high' nor 'low' then one of the three threads does not get created.  Not handling this problem will result in failures in the code when `pthread_join()` is called

Comment: what happens if `argv[2]` is not equal to `sched` nor `priority`?

Comment: what happens if `argv[1]` is not equal to `multi`?

Comment: need to check the returned value from calls to `pthread_create()` and `pthread_attr_setschedparam()` and `pthread_attr_setschedpolicy()`. Do NOT assume that a system function worked.

Comment: when, at the command prompt, you type: `./project multi sched FIFO`  is the text: "Scheduling FIFO" displayed?  When you type: `./project multi sched RR` is the text: "Do RR algorithm" displayed?  When you type: `./project multi sched FIFO/RR` is the message: "Scheduling parameter invalid" displayed?

Comment: how do you know that the thread attributes are not being used?